# Android service crash onlocationchanged when app camera is open

Tags: android, service, gps

I 
I'm developing an application that implements an Android service that sends data onChangeLocation GPS function
It's works but testing the app on different phones (of my testers) sometimes, opening the camera app, my app crash (i have a crash report based on Firebase but the crash is inside the service so i don't have any information about the origin of crash). I can't repeat myself the problem.
Thanks for suggestions and sorry for my poor english

Luca

Comment: Without proper error we can't say anything.

Comment: i cant figure out the error. The complete code is https://github.com/c1p81/RunnerTracker